# dependent and conditional validations not working

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Hi all am trying to do validations for a text field which is depends on other selected value .there is two columns buyer and reference number.so the validation is  when i select particular names in buyer column then the reference must be required.

Below is my code

**model::**

```
public static $rules = array(
    'delivery_contact_no' => 'required|numeric',
    'external_ref_number' => 'required',
);
```

**controller::**

```
$check = false;

if ($_POST["user"] == '11Street') {

    $check = true;

    if (Input::get('external_ref_number') == "") {

        $rules = array(
            'external_ref_number' => 'required'
        );

        $messages = array(
            'external_ref_number.required' => 'The External Reference Number Must be required ',
        );
    }

    if ($check) {
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $message);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
        }
    }
}
```

I am inserting input data like below:

```
$get = array(
    'user'                => trim($_POST["user"]),
    'external_ref_number' => trim(Input::get('external_ref_number')),
);
```

so the validation is when I select particular names in buyer column then the reference must be required. below is view code

**view::**

```
<div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('user')) has-error @endif">

    {{ Form::label('user', 'Buyer *', array('class'=> 'col-lg-2 control-label')) }}


    <div class="col-lg-4">

        {{ Form::text('user', Input::old('user'), array('class'=> 'form-control', 'autofocus' => 'autofocus', 'readonly' => 'readonly')) }}

        {{ $errors->first('user', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') }}

        <input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-btn">

                <span class="pull-left"><button id="selectUserBtn" class="btn btn-primary selectUserBtn" href="/transaction/ajaxcustomer"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Select Buyer</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="form-group required {{ $errors->first('external_ref_number', 'has-error') }}">

    {{ Form::label('external_ref_number', 'External reference number ', array('class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label')) }}

    <div class="col-lg-4">

        {{ Form::text('external_ref_number', $orderMappedInfo['external_ref_number'], ['placeholder' => 'External reference number', 'class' => 'form-control']) }}

        {{ $errors->first('external_ref_number', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') }}
    </div>
</div>
```

The validation code which I wrote is not working. Please help me to solve this issue.
I am trying to do validations for a text field which is depends on other selected value.
There are two columns buyer and reference number.
so the validation is  when i select particular names in buyer column then the reference must be required.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: am using version 4.2